# CommitFailedError when reading messages from Kafka (Debezium) using Python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, debezium

I'm building a Python Kafka consumer for Debezium messages. 
At the moment I'm facing the following issue:

When inserting 1000 records consecutively, 1000 change messages are produced by Debezium. The Python Kafka consumer starts to process them one by one, but fails to do them all. In fact, it stops somewhere between message 650 and 750 and starts again around message 150. So, it actually gets stuck in a loop. The consumer configuration was as follows:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer('topic', 
                        bootstrap_servers='',
                        auto_offset_reset='earliest', 
                        group_id='debezium', 
                        enable_auto_commit = True)

for message in consumer:
    # do something with the message
```

I suspected that the consumer wasn't committing its offsets correctly. Therefore, I changed the configuration to the following:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer('topic', 
                        bootstrap_servers='',
                        auto_offset_reset='earliest', 
                        group_id='debezium', 
                        enable_auto_commit = False)

for message in consumer:
    # do something with the message

    consumer.commit()
```

Now, it's committing is offsets as it should and it doesn't get stuck in a loop. However, it produces the following error between message 650 and 750:

> CommitFailedError: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already
>               rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member.
>               This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll()
>               was longer than the configured max_poll_interval_ms, which
>               typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much
>               time message processing. You can address this either by
>               increasing the rebalance timeout with max_poll_interval_ms,
>               or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll()
>               with max_poll_records.

Any suggestions?

Thanks by advance

Comment: What's your `max_poll_interval_ms` set to? It sounds like it may be set too low, but that might not explain why it takes 650-750 messages for this issue to surface. What about your `max_poll_records` value? I'd perhaps try reducing that, too.

Comment: `max_poll_interval_ms: 300000` and `max_poll_records: 500`, which are the default values. I'll try if adjusting them helps.